# TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, ngx-bootstrap

I am writing test cases for ngx-bootstrap (bsDateRangePickerDirective) in angular 7. but when I am trying to open the bsdaterangePickerDirective instance from spec file I am getting error that Can not read property show of undefined.

Following is the code that I have written:

component.ts File

```
@ViewChild("sdp") sdatepicker: BsDaterangepickerDirective;
// Function
openDatePicker() {
    this.sdatepicker.show();
  }
```

Component.spec.ts file

```
import { ComponentFixture, async, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NameComponent } from "./name-box.component";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { BsDatepickerModule, BsDaterangepickerDirective } from "ngx-bootstrap";
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from "@angular/common/http/testing";

describe('NameComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SearchBoxComponent>;
  let component: SearchBoxComponent;

  beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [NameComponent],
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        BsDatepickerModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NameComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

  });


  it('Should open date picker', () => {
    const dateSpy = spyOn(BsDaterangepickerDirective.prototype, "show").and.returnValue(true);
    component.openDatePicker('sdatepicker');
    expect(dateSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});
```

Component Template File:

```
<div class="grid-search-datepicker date-selector">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="start-date-selector_{{searchTableId}}" [(ngModel)]="dateRange.startDate"
        bsDatepicker #sdp="bsDatepicker" (onHidden)="updateMinEndDate()" [bsConfig]="startDateConfig" placeholder="{{l10n.fromdate}}"
        readonly>
      <i class="icon-small-calendar text-blue open-datetimepicker" (click)='openDatePicker("sdatepicker")' aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is the ViewChild in your component template?

Comment: And also you need to change it like following in order to access `BsDaterangepickerDirective` properties: `@ViewChild("sdp",{read: BsDaterangepickerDirective}) sdatepicker: BsDaterangepickerDirective;`

Comment: @Mike: Through ViewChild I am accessing the bsDatePicker template from the HTML with sdp as a local reference variable

Comment: @HarunYılmaz: I tried your solution but did not get success

Comment: No mine is not the whole solution. It is just a part of it. I cannot say anything unless seeing the template file

Comment: @HarunYılmaz: I have added the template file change. Please check it once and any suggestion your help will be helpful for me.

Comment: @Mike: you got any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

In your template you are using `bsDatepicker` but in the component you are referring to it as `BsDaterangepickerDirective`. I think it will work if you change the template to:

```html
<div class="grid-search-datepicker date-selector">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="start-date-selector_{{searchTableId}}" 
    [(ngModel)]="dateRange.startDate"
    bsDaterangepicker
    #sdp="bsDaterangepicker"
    (onHidden)="updateMinEndDate()"
    [bsConfig]="startDateConfig"
    placeholder="{{l10n.fromdate}}"
    readonly
  >
  <i class="icon-small-calendar text-blue open-datetimepicker" 
    (click)='openDatePicker("sdatepicker")'
    aria-hidden="true"
  >
  </i>
</div>
```

See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sgaq4e

Comment: Mike do you have any other solution

Comment: What I have said is working, I have included a stackblitz

Comment: Yes Mike, functionality wise it is working but test case is still getting failed